# ECDH with P-256 generating shared secret using static keys bouncy castle c#

Tags: c#, cryptography, bouncycastle

I am trying to create a shared secret using the ECDH-P-256 algorithm using the bouncy castle (c#) API.  I need to use 2 static keys to generate this.  These will then get hashed with some other (varying) data to produce a new key.

Does anyone know how to perform ECDH by using the C# API? I have been looking for a while and can only find code that uses Java.

Comment: BC API is rather similar for both C# and Java. Have you tried converting from a Java sample? Furthermore, the question is a bit unclear to me. Are you referring to ephemeral-static Diffie-Hellman, where one key pair is static?

Comment: In this case both keys are static.  As I said the variation comes from hashing the resulting data with some other varying data.  it looks like the c# lib has not been updated since 2011 so I am thinking this is a dead project.

Comment: I would not call it dead, but I'm pretty certain that the focus is on FIPS validation and the Java code base. Asking for samples is off topic, I would just take a look at the `ECDHBasicAgreement` class and go from there. Make sure your ECDH implementation is according to  800-58A though and validate your public keys!

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have found something to proceed.
For others landing here, please take a look at my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/31419559/190476 (to my own question). I've explained one variant of Key-derivation using ECDH and as per NIST SP 800-56A, section 5.8.1 together with the BouncyCastle C# API